# Sync my Music from Windows with the correct Added Date?

Tags: itunes, windows, music, macbook-pro

I recently moved my music via USB from my windows to my macbook. All the songs were on iTunes and were arranged by `Date Added`. Once I moved them to the macbook, they all scrambled around with incorrect dates !! I thought iTunes saves the META data in the files so that they can be read again using another device.

Is there a way to arrange my songs by the correct `Date Added`

I still have the songs in my Window's iTunes if this helps at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4796

This Apple support document answers your question very well. Migration Assistant will copy over your iTunes library with metadata. Before that, delete the iTunes library you copied over from your previous attempt.

Comment: Can you choose what to migrate ?? I am only interested in migrating my iTunes library and nothing else

Comment: Yep you can. It says in the article, read it.